# Time based invocation of RxJava operators on events

Tags: rx-java

I have following code:

```
Observable
                .just(8, 9, 10)
                .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("A: " + i))
                .filter(i -> {
                    return i % 3 > 0;
                })
                .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("B: " + i))
                .map(i -> {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    return "#" + i * 10;
                })
                .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("C: " + s))
                .filter(s -> s.length() < 4)
                .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("D: " + s));
```

Output is:

```
A: 8
B: 8
C: #80
D: #80
A: 9
A: 10
B: 10
C: #100
```

Output suggests that first 8 goes through all the observable operators, then 9 and then 10. Even if processing of 8 takes time in map operator, 9 is not emitted to filter operator. Why is it so? Seems I haven't understood correctly how RxJava works.

Comment: Because RxJava is synchronous by default. The first value is pushed all the way to the subscriber on the same thread thus `sleep` blocks the execution of the subsequent values 9 and 10. You have to introduce threading via `observeOn` for example to make the producer and consumer run on separate threads.

Comment: Ok,basically if there are n operators, then its like that the cumulative action of those n operators is applied on every single element sequentially. So if a part of this cumulative action is blocking, then entire pipeline of operators is blocked. Btw, even if I introduce threading, still blocking would be there as operators would separate producer and consumer, and operators together constitute consumer..right?

Comment: Operators are practically consumers and producers, i.e., they receive individual values and send out individual values. There is usually some form of transformation between the receiving and sending out. Since this is Java, receiving and sending is a form of a method call, thus as long as such method calls don't return, subsequent operations can't progress. With `observeOn`, you can decouple this two side and thus allow one end to proceed without waiting for the other end.